# How do I properly bind directories inside chroot jails using fstab?

Tags: mount, mysql, fstab, chroot

I'm running nginx, PHP-FPM and MySQL on Debian Wheezy. I've set up chroot jails (with `debootstrap`) for each individual virtual host in `/srv/`. Everything is working like one would expect, but after each reboot I had to manually `mount --bind /proc /srv/chrootjail/proc` and `mount --bind /run/mysqld /srv/chrootjail/run/mysqld`.

This is why I added the following lines to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/proc       /srv/chrootjail/proc       none rw,bind 0 0
/run/mysqld /srv/chrootjail/run/mysqld none rw,bind 0 0
```

`/srv/chrootjail/proc` gets mounted properly, but `/srv/chrootjail/run/mysqld` does **not** and I can't find the reason why. `/srv/chrootjail/run/mysqld` just remains empty, although there are files in `/run/mysqld`. However, `mount -a` fixes the problem. For obvious reasons this is not the solution I was hoping for.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mount anything on `/run` in the chroot? It could be something like `/srv/chrootjail/run/mysqld` is mounted and then something is mounted at `/srv/chrootjail/run` shadowing it.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable hint, but unfortunately that's not the case for me. There's no other entry in `/etc/fstab` but the two I added plus the ones for `/`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc` and `/sys`. `/srv/chrootjail/etc/fstab` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very limited knowledge what `mount --bind` even does really, but I think I might have figured out why I'm facing this problem with `/run/mysqld` in particular. I've just noticed [`/run` (previously `/var/run`) is a tmpfs](https://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory) and thus it gets emptied during a reboot. So my guess is that  `/run/mysqld` doesn't exist when `/etc/fstab` gets parsed. It's the init-script `/etc/init.d/mysql` that checks for `/run/mysqld` and creates it if needed with this line:

```
# Could be removed during boot
test -e /run/mysqld || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /run/mysqld
```

As a workaround I simply added a `mount -a` after that line. I guess I could just have it create the mysqld folder anywhere(?) but inside of `/run` (or `/var/run`), too. However, if nobody can tell me a *better* way to do it, I'll stick to this workaround. Thanks for  your time!